# How to get radio button checked in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm stuck with something supposed simple: get the id of the checked radio button to give it to a function.

Please look at the code bellow:

In HTML :

```
<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="r in rewards">
        <li>
          <div class="radio">
              <input name="fakeform" type="radio" ng-value="r.id" ng-model="theId" />
              <label for="radio">{{r.name}}</label>
          </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

...

```
<button ng-click="use_reward(theId)">
OK
</button>
```

In controller.js

```
$scope.use_reward = function(reward_id){
      alert(reward_id);
```

The alert box returns `undefined` instead of the id when the function is called.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="r.id" ng-model="$parent.theId" />

<button ng-click="use_reward(theId)">
OK
</button>
```

Or just use `$scope.theId` within `use_reward`.

To get name **and** id pass the whole object:

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="r" ng-model="$parent.theReward" />

<button ng-click="use_reward(theReward)">

$scope.use_reward = function(reward){
  alert(reward.id);
  alert(reward.name);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it still doesn't work. I updated my question with the updated code. Thx.

Comment: @DavidW. My mistake. I've updated the answer. BTW: You should keep the original question, so that others with the same problem know how to solve it.

Comment: That works thanks a lot. Bonus question: would you know how to retrieve r.id **AND** r.name to call `use_reward(theId, theName)?`

Comment: @DavidW. Pass the whole object. See the updated answer.